# Secure Web API With Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

Can anyone provide me with instructions on how to setup and secure a Web API project using Azure AD?  I can create the project but when I navigate to /api/values/, I get a 401 response.  The application has been added to the list of applications in my Azure AD directory.

I found a blog post [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/23/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-azure-ad-and-katana/) that appears to address this topic but the steps do not match my environment.  Perhaps this is because it is a bit outdated?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Web API examples at https://github.com/AzureADSamples, specifically [WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet) and [AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-UserIdentity-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-UserIdentity-DotNet).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at everything you suggested (yet) but from what I have looked at so far indicates that this is the information I have been looking for (or at least will allow me to talk about the subject more intelligently, albeit slightly).